# CSV Formatting using Python Pandas - Group 8 lines separated by commas on same line

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Im stuck trying to fix a csv file. The csv has 8 columns and all of them are on single lines. I need to be able to add a "," (Already did that) and then bring up 8 comas to the same line.

Example :
data
data
data
data
data
data

data, data, data, data, data, data

Every 8 Lines.

```
import pandas as pd

filepath = "file.txt"
with open(filepath) as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    
with open(filepath, "w") as f:
    for line in lines:
        f.write(line + ",\n")
        

dataframe1 = pd.read_csv("file.txt")
# storing this dataframe in a csv file
dataframe1.to_csv('Exported.csv',  
                  index = None)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify every 8th line of the input file:

1. open the input file for reading and create a new file for writing
2. iterate the input file, line by line
3. every 8th line, transform the line (before writing)
4. write the line

For purpose of illustrating how to get some fine control over this, I'm going to fix every 4th line of this file:

```
R01_C1 R01_C2 R01_C3 R01_C4
R02_C1 R02_C2 R02_C3 R02_C4
R03_C1 R03_C2 R03_C3 R03_C4
R04_C1 R04_C2 R04_C3 R04_C4
R05_C1 R05_C2 R05_C3 R05_C4
R06_C1 R06_C2 R06_C3 R06_C4
R07_C1 R07_C2 R07_C3 R07_C4
R08_C1 R08_C2 R08_C3 R08_C4
R09_C1 R09_C2 R09_C3 R09_C4
R10_C1 R10_C2 R10_C3 R10_C4
R11_C1 R11_C2 R11_C3 R11_C4
R12_C1 R12_C2 R12_C3 R12_C4
```

I run this:

```py
with open("bad-file.txt") as in_f, open("good-file.txt", "w") as out_f:
    for i, line in enumerate(in_f):
        if i % 4 == 0:
            line = line.replace(" ", ",")
        out_f.write(line)
```

and end up with this:

```
R01_C1,R01_C2,R01_C3,R01_C4 <-- line 1
R02_C1 R02_C2 R02_C3 R02_C4
R03_C1 R03_C2 R03_C3 R03_C4
R04_C1 R04_C2 R04_C3 R04_C4
R05_C1,R05_C2,R05_C3,R05_C4 <-- line 5
R06_C1 R06_C2 R06_C3 R06_C4
R07_C1 R07_C2 R07_C3 R07_C4
R08_C1 R08_C2 R08_C3 R08_C4
R09_C1,R09_C2,R09_C3,R09_C4 <-- line 9
R10_C1 R10_C2 R10_C3 R10_C4
R11_C1 R11_C2 R11_C3 R11_C4
R12_C1 R12_C2 R12_C3 R12_C4
```

You can control where the replacement starts by playing with the `start` value of `enumerate()`:

```py
for i, line in enumerate(in_f, 1):
```

yields

```
R01_C1 R01_C2 R01_C3 R01_C4
R02_C1 R02_C2 R02_C3 R02_C4
R03_C1 R03_C2 R03_C3 R03_C4
R04_C1,R04_C2,R04_C3,R04_C4 <-- line 4
R05_C1 R05_C2 R05_C3 R05_C4
R06_C1 R06_C2 R06_C3 R06_C4
R07_C1 R07_C2 R07_C3 R07_C4
R08_C1,R08_C2,R08_C3,R08_C4 <-- line 8
R09_C1 R09_C2 R09_C3 R09_C4
R10_C1 R10_C2 R10_C3 R10_C4
R11_C1 R11_C2 R11_C3 R11_C4
R12_C1,R12_C2,R12_C3,R12_C4 <-- line 12
```